# Azure Function "Local" Files

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I am creating an HTTP Function in Python that will take a csv blob from storage, do some things with scipy and matplotlib, and spit out a pdf to the same container using wkhtmltopdf. I have no issue doing any of this on my local system, but like most things, it stops working when I deploy it.

The function will need to overwrite a pickle file (in blob storage), create several images (.png) and an html file and reference the exe for wkhtmltopdf to convert those pngs and html to a pdf. The pickle part comes first and snags this error on this line (from azure portal logs):

```
Exception while executing function: Functions.Summaries <--- Result: Failure Exception: UnsupportedOperation: not writable Stack: File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.7/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 345, in _handle__invocation_request self.__run_sync_func, invocation_id, fi.func, args) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 57, in run result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs) File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.7/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 480, in __run_sync_func return func(**params) File "/home/site/wwwroot/Summaries/__init__.py", line 30, in main out_pdf = invoice_stats(add_df, update_df, output_html_url, invoice_html_url) File "/home/site/wwwroot/Summaries/__init__.py", line 357, in invoice_stats f.write(message_html)
```

```
update_df.to_pickle('InvoiceHistory.p')
```

So it looks like I cannot write to the current directory, this will prove to be an issue with the images.

1. Is this the wrong way of going about this situation?
2. Can someone ask me the right questions to narrow this down to the root problem?

Below is a subset of my code:

```
sas_token_output_html = generate_blob_sas(account_name='***',
                            account_key='***',
                            container_name=container,
                            blob_name='output.html',
                            permission=BlobSasPermissions(read=True, write=True, create=True),
                            expiry=datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(hours=1))

output_html_url =f'https://***.blob.core.windows.net/{container}/output.html?{sas_token_output_html}'

template_vars = {
        'week_day':'Wednesday',
        'month':datetime.date.today().strftime('%B'),
        'day': datetime.date.today().day,
        'year': datetime.date.today().year,
        ...}
        
message_html = template.render(template_vars)
with open('output_html_url','w') as f:
    f.write(message_html)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you should have at least temporary write access to a part of the file system. have you tried to just write to /tmp/myfile.p?

Comment: I have tried creating directories to remove when the function is complete, that has been causing the host to restart. ```with open('output_html_url','w') as f: 
  f.write(message_html)``` fails as well.

Comment: COuld you please provide your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to store anything locally, but I was able to store my helper files/function in a storage blob and download the blobs locally using:

```
with open(os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), 'input.csv'), 'wb') as input:
        input.write(blob_client.download_blob().readall())
```

This does not solve the specific problem, but it is an acceptable work-around.

Answer (score -1):

I came across this snippet hoping to accomplish something similar. I took out the pieces irrelevant to me. This worked to create a file when using the testing function of function apps in vscode (func start):
(from https://option40.com/blog/azure)

```
import logging
import tempfile
import azure.functions as func


def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    dir_path = tempfile.gettempdir()
    file = dir_path + "\test.txt"
    name = "Me"

    with open(file, mode="w") as f:
        f.write(f"{name}")
        
    with open(file) as f:
        new = f.read()

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"{file}, {new}")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
             status_code=200
        )
```

My result: C:\Users\myName\AppData\Local\Temp\test.txt, Me